# How to add image to html from sd card

Tags: android

I have an html file. I show it as webview. I tried to add image on it from sd but i couldn't.
Here is the code i used:

```
<tr height="21" style='height:15.75pt'>
    <td height="21" class="xl71" style='height:15.75pt'>&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="borderLeft">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>
    <![if !vml]>
      <span style='mso-ignore:vglayout;add
  position:absolute;z-index:20;margin-left:24px;margin-top:3px;width:73px;
  height:144px'><img src="/sdcard/SurucuImza.jpg" alt="" width="168" height="120"       v:shapes="Picture_x0020_421" /></span>
      <![endif]>
      <span
  style='mso-ignore:vglayout2'>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
```

I have used the path here:

```
<img src="/sdcard/SurucuImza.jpg" alt="" width="168" height="120" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_421" />
```

But it didn't work. I can't show the image.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

try as

```
    String base = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
    String imagePath = "file:/"+ base + "/SurucuImza.jpg";
    String strimg="<img src=\""+ imagePath + "\" alt=\"\" width=\"168\" height=\"120\" v:shapes=\Picture_x0020_421\" />";
```

Comment: Dynamic path is important.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "file://mnt/sdcard/SurucuImza.jpg".
You might need to allow th access with this line :
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would do... is to copy the image into your working directory. If you dont do that, when you remove your SD card... you can say goodbye to your picture.

In case that this is not possible, just put the full path to that place.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
src="file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "your_image_folder_name/SurucuImza.jpg"
```

insteed of

```
src="/sdcard/SurucuImza.jpg"
```

**NOTE: give the permission to manifest first..**

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```